# How to get Latitude/Longitude span in Google Map V2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a task for move my app to Google Maps Android APIs V2. Now, I need to get Latitude/Longitude span. I used `MapView.getLatitudeSpan()` and `MapView.getLongitudeSpan()` in previous version APIs. Now I can't find something like this in V2.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the lat/lng span:

```
VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can we get center of the map visible part lat lng

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First obtain a Projection using [`GoogleMap.getProjection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection%28%29).  Then you can call [`Projection.getVisibleRegion()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#getVisibleRegion%28%29) to obtain a VisibleRegion which has a LatLngBounds.

The reason why a LatitudeSpan and Longitude span no longer makes sense is because the map can now be rotated and tilted and so viewport is no longer a latitude/longitude aligned rectangle on the map.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>This way works for me:</strike>

```
CameraPosition camPos2 = mapa.getCameraPosition();
LatLng pos = camPos2.target;
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Lat: " + pos.latitude + " - Lng: " +pos.longitude,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

---

Oops, i misunderstood the question, i mean i did not saw "span" word.
According the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) the correct would be:

First get the bounds:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = gMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

And then ask if any point is in bounds:

```
LatLng point = new LatLng (latitude, longitude);
if(bounds.contains(point)){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
if (bounds.contains(ROMA)) {
   marker = googleMap.addMarker(
     new MarkerOptions()
      .position(ROMA)
      .title("Hello")
      .snippet("Nice Place")
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
     );     
   System.out.println("Marker added");
}
```

Add the marker only when it falls in the visible region