# GoogleMap InfoWindowAdapter download data on thread and update when finished

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using a custom InfoWindow adapter class for my markers to handle when the user presses on the icon to display some information:

```
mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomMarkerInfoWindowAdapter(downloadService, getLayoutInflater(), markersList));
```

Relevant snippet from my custom InfoWindowAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    final View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
    final TextView textThing = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.markerInfoThing);
    textThing.setText("Downloading data...");

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            Thing thing = downloadService.getThing(thingId);

            // this doesn't work - and yes thing.getName() returns a valid string
            textThing.setText(thing.getName());
        }
    }.start();

    return currentView;
}
```

The second call to `setText` doesn't occur until after `getInfoContents` has returned and the TextView on the InfoWindow is never updated. I noticed there are no other functions (such as `notifyDataHasChanged`) in `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter` to override, therefore I'm wondering if it's possible to do this?

Comment: so did you found an answer to this?

Comment: I'm trying to get one of the various solutions you linked to work. I have tried most of them, but I can't get any of them to work... yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `getInfoContents` is returning the `View` before the data has been downloaded, and because of that, the `TextView` is not updated.

You should download the content first, and update the `InfoWindow` after you have it downloaded. You can accomplish this by using `AsyncTask`, and you can show the `InfoWindow` on the `onPostExecute` method call, and for that, you will need to keep track of the current `Marker`.

See these links:

1. [How to image from url into InfoWindowAdapter android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346254/how-to-image-from-url-into-infowindowadapter-android)
2. [I my using google mapV2 and i m downloading image from google place api and want to display in the popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279442/i-my-using-google-mapv2-and-i-m-downloading-image-from-google-place-api-and-want).
3. [How to check if an Google Maps InfoWindow is still displayed before updating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745818/how-to-check-if-an-google-maps-infowindow-is-still-displayed-before-updating-it)

There is also this approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512984/399459):

> You should be doing `Marker.showInfoWindow()` on marker that is
>   currently showing info window when you receive model update.
>
> So you need to do 3 things:
>
> 1. create model and not put all the downloading into `CustomMarkerInfoWindowAdapter`
> 2. save reference to `Marker` (call it `markerShowingInfoWindow`) from `getInfoContents(Marker marker)`
> 3. when model notifies you of download complete, call
>
>    ```
>    if (markerShowingInfoWindow != null && markerShowingInfoWindow.isShowingInfoWindow()) 
>    {
>        markerShowingInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();
>    }
>    ```

Hope this helps you.