# Move camera position to fit LatLngBounds with regard to marker height

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I want to move camera to position to fit `LatLngBounds` with regard to marker height. So far I'm able for fit the anchors of markers with this code:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Marker marker : markerList) {
    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

int padding = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.home_map_padding); // offset from edges of the map in pixels
cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

It produces output like this:
[image: my output so far]
As you can see there's empty space at the bottom (this is `int padding`). **I'd like to have the padding to be equal like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is similar to the one posted here:

[Defining a CameraUpdate with LatLngBounds with different padding values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970158/defining-a-cameraupdate-with-latlngbounds-with-different-padding-values)

The solution is to set the top padding of the actual `GoogleMap` to the height of your marker icon.

Something like this will do:

```java
Drawable drawable = <YOUR DRAWABLE HERE>;
final int padding = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
map.setPadding(0, padding, 0, 0);
```

Looks like this with my custom marker image (rulers inserted for comparison):

[image]

Comment: In fact my question is a duplicate. But anyway you saved my day (or even few of them).

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Glad that my answer was helpful. I was actually searching for a solution myself and found your question (and the other one).

Comment: Wrong because indicator automatically move

Comment: @delive Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes see my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552160/map-v2-how-to-add-margin-marker-is-possile/33552754#33552754

Comment: @delive There is no post from you there and the answer there pretty much says the same I suggested, so what is it you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to get the height of the marker unless you're using a custom marker. However given that the markers stay the same size you can scroll the camera view up by a set amount.

You're going to have to play around a bit with how much to scroll by but once you get the value you can then scale it based on screen density if necessary.

Comment: The problem is: I know marker height (in pixels) but I don't know what will be map zoom after animation so I can't reflect that height in padding here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int)