# Android Google Map v2 - move marker to clicked position and update geo coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I detect user's current location automatically and center the map around the marker.

I want to enable the user to click elsewhere on the map, and the marker to appear at the position they clicked, and the lat/lon to be updated to that new position.

How do I do  that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739075/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-span-in-google-map-v2-for-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
 Marker marker;
 GoogleMap mMap;

 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            System.out.println(latlng);

       }
   });
```

Comment: This works, but the blue point that indicates my position remains at my position. and the new marker is not a blue dot, but a red water drop thingy upside down?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add a marker with the current location you have to implement [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

With the following code you can add a marker with your location and move the camera:

```
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                    .title("My Location"));

            /* ..and Animate camera to center on that location !
             * (the reason for we created this custom Location Source !) */
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        }
```

In order to add a maker when the user taps inside the map you can use [OnMapLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener.html)

```
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .snippet(""));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, [OnMapClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html)